# How to use string variable value in a command for a label named after that string?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an iOS app in Swift. My goal is to write something like:

```
i = 2
txt1 = "team\(i)ScoreLabel"
txt1.text = "Something"
```

But obviously this doesn't work. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: All you need is an array of labels, not labels with separate variable names.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest and simplest way is to give your UILabel a tag. Then in it's vc call

```
 ( self.view.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel).text = "Something"
```

Comment: When I run this, I get the error "Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x11050eba8) to 'UILabel' (0x110512e10)".

Comment: You have to have a UIlabel in your UIView. And set the tag of UILabel to 2 in IB.